# Generating a ScatterLine plot at one sheet but data series from other multiple sheets by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm extremely new to VBA. I need to create a scatterline plot at Sheet1 with data from multiple sheets, each series named "E2" at each sheet, the x-axis is from "P25" to "P600" and the Y-axis is from "Z25" to "Z600" at each sheet. Here is the code I write:

```
Sub graphy23()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim co As ChartObject
Dim sc1 As SeriesCollection
Dim ser1 As Series

Set co = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Add(Range("A2").Left, Range("A2").Top, 500, 500)
'co.Name =

 With co.Chart

.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
.HasLegend = True
.HasTitle = False

Set sc1 = .SeriesCollection
Set ser1 = sc1.NewSeries
For Each ws In Worksheets
With ser1

If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
 
.Name = Range("E2").Value
.XValues = Range(Range("P25"), Range("P600"))
.Values = Range(Range("Z25"), Range("Z600"))

End If
End With
Next ws
End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the error or issue with your code?

Comment: It generates one single scatterline plot at sheet1 with data only from Sheet1, I think my code should generate one single scatterline plot at sheet1 with data from other multiple sheets besides Sheet1, Thank you very much!

Comment: You are only adding one series to the chart since `Set ser1 = sc1.NewSeries` is outside the `For` loop. You also need to qualify the worksheet that any `Range` is on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, BigBen. I have changed the code based on your advise and it works:

```
Set co = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Add(Range("A2").Left, Range("A2").Top, 500, 500)
'co.Name =

 With co.Chart

.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
.HasLegend = True
.HasTitle = False


For Each ws In Worksheets

If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then

ws.Activate
 
Set sc1 = .SeriesCollection
Set ser1 = sc1.NewSeries
 
With ser1

.Name = Range("E2").Value
.XValues = Range(Range("P25"), Range("P600"))
.Values = Range(Range("Z25"), Range("Z600"))


End With

End If

Next ws
End With
End Sub
```